# Simple proof that $\sum_{k = 1}^\infty \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_k b_n / (k + n) \lesssim (\sum_k a_k^2)^{1/2} (\sum_n b_n^2)^{1/2}$

Tags: inequality

I have a complicated proof involving real interpolation + restricted bounds on operators, but I can only imagine there is a simpler proof of this statement involving some combinations of basic inequalities, such as Cauchy-Schwartz.

Comment: Interesting ineq, may I know where it comes from?

Comment: Let's present why this question is NON-trivial. Firstly, if we replace $\frac{1}{k+n}$ by $1$ for all terms. The resulted ineq $$ \sum_k \sum_n a_k b_n \lesssim ( \sum a_k^2)^{1/2}( \sum b_n^2)^{1/2}$$ fails delibrately. Now if we look closely, we the see sum $k+n$ is associated to the product $a_kb_n$. So we expect this ineq should be trivial if we use power series. However, the "trivial" approach by power series yields something not really promising, that is:$$| \sum_{k,n} \frac{a_kb_n}{k+n+1}x^{k+n+1}| \le \| a\|_2 \| b\|_2  \int_0^{|x|} \frac{1}{1-t}dt $$

Comment: It is not promising because the ineq's constant goes to infinity as $|x|$ converges to $1$, and we want $|x|=1$

Comment: This is one of the inequalities known as [Hilbert's Inequality](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~steele/Publications/Books/CSMC/CSMC_HilbertandCompensatingDifficulties.pdf).

Comment: @JimmyK4542: Thank you, I'm kinda embarrassed of my lack of knowledge

Comment: Don't feel bad. I didn't know what it was called until I needed a bound on the operator norm of the Hilbert matrix for my research. If I remember correctly, It took me a few hours of Googling to find that link.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! This was a question from a University of Madison analysis past qualifying exam I'm preparing to lead a set of  preparation sessions for, and I wasn't sure how to solve this question.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the ambiguity about the convergence, assume $a_n,b_n \ge 0$ and $\sum a_n^2 =1$.
We have:
$$
\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{k\ge 1}\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{a_kb_n}{n+k}\right)^2 &\le \left( \sum_{k \ge 1} a_k^2 \right)\left( \sum_{k \ge 1} \left( \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{b_n}{n+k} \right)^2 \right)
\\
& \le  \sum_{k \ge 1} \left( \sum_{n \ge 1}  \frac{b_n^2\sqrt{n}}{n+k} \right) \underbrace{ \left( \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+k)}\right)}_{=\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+k)}+ \sum_{n \ge k+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}(n+k)}}
\\
& \le \sum_{k \ge 1} \left( \sum_{n \ge 1}  \frac{b_n^2\sqrt{n}}{n+k} \right)\left( 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}+2\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \right)
\\
&= 4\sum_{n \ge 1} b_n^2 \sqrt{n}\left( \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}(k+n)} \right) 
\\
& \le  4\sum_{n \ge 1} b_n^2 \sqrt{n} \frac{4}{\sqrt{n}} (\text{ like above})
\\
& \le 16 \sum_{n \ge 1} b_n^2
\end{align}
$$
Hence the conclusion.